# VC inline asm - shifting with rcl (rcr)

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly, bit-shift

I'm using the following function to shift the data of a vector by 1 bit (mult by 2):

```
vec shl(vec n) {
    n.resize(n.size() + 1, 0);
    unsigned int* adr = n.data();
    unsigned int s = n.size();
    _asm {
        clc
        mov ecx, 0
        mov edx, dword ptr [adr]
    nloop:
        mov eax, dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4]
        rcl eax, 1
        mov dword ptr [edx + ecx * 4], eax
        inc ecx
        jc carryisset      ; check carry - breakpoint
        jmp nocarry        ; ~ breakpoint
    carryisset :           ; ~ breakpoint
        jmp nocarry        ; ~ breakpoint
    nocarry:               ; ~ breakpoint
        cmp ecx, dword ptr [s]
        jl nloop        
    };
    return n;
};
```

So, I've read that `rcl` uses the carry bit and add it to the high bit. But when the carry bit is not set according to the debugger, the rcl continues adding it to `eax`.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<unsigned int> vec;
const unsigned int uint_max = (unsigned int)(~0);
vec n1 = { uint_max, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
vec n2

int main() {
    n2 = shl(n1);
    for (auto i : n2)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
};
```

Output:

```
4294967294 5 5 3 1 1 1 1
```

Stepping through the code with debugger:

```
loop: first iteration (ecx = 0)
eax <- uint_max
eax <- rotate left with carry (rcl)
now eax is uint_max - 1
jumps to carryisset (with jc), so there is a carry

loop: second iteration (ecx = 1)
eax <- 2
eax <- rotate left with carry (rcl)
now eax is 2 << 2 + (carry)1 = 5
jumps to nocarry (with jc), so there is no carry

loop: third iteration (ecx = 2)
eax <- 2
eax <- rotate left with carry (rcl)
now eax is 2 << 2 + carry (should be 0, not set), but eax gives 5 too, like there were carry.
jumps to nocarry (with jc), so there is no carry (at least according to jc)

...ect
```

So, there is no carry after the first iteration in this case, but the carry does not 'reset'.
This implementation came from an SO post [Large binary shifts in 8086 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209851/large-binary-shifts-in-8086-assembly) (accepted answer):

> First, make sure the carry flag is zero. Then:
>   1. Pull 4 bytes into a register
>   2. RCR   - in my case RCL
>   3. Write back out
>   4. Repeat with the next 4 bytes

However the carry bit is always on when I rotate left (or tried with right, same results: in case of `vec(2,0,0,0,0...)` it is `vec(1, uint_max/2 + 1, uint max/2 + 1, ...)`)

ps: I made a working shift avoiding the carry and checking the highest bit, but it is a overcomplicated I think:

```
    _asm {
    clc
    mov edx, dword ptr [adr]
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor eax, eax
nloop:
    mov eax, dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4]
    push edx
    mov edx, ebx
    mov ebx, eax
    and ebx, 0x80000000
    shr ebx, 31
    shl eax, 1
    add eax, edx
    pop edx
    mov dword ptr [edx + ecx * 4], eax
    inc ecx
    xor eax, eax
    cmp ecx, dword ptr [s]
    jl nloop        
};
```

What is the problem with the first code, how to use `rcl` and `rcr` for shifting?

Comment: Code it in C and see what the compiler outputs

Comment: The CMP instruction changes the carry.  You'll need to re-think this.

Comment: hm, I've deleted the CMP, that really works (only checked with debugger), however now I have to find something to check the counter to end the loop. pushf and popf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to Hans. See the comment.)

The working code:

```
    clc
    mov ecx, 0
    mov edx, dword ptr[adr]
nloop:
    pushf
    cmp ecx, dword ptr [s]
    je fin
    popf
    mov eax, dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4]
    rcl eax, 1
    mov dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4], eax
    inc ecx
    jmp nloop
fin:
    popf
```

I clear the flags first. In the main loop, `pushf` the flags just for a `cmp`, after `popf` them. For this, I moved the compare to the begin of the loop. For the `fin` just `popf` the the flags after the jump to avoid ESP errors.